# How to exclude 2 directories from workspace cleanup in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to create a job that deletes all my folders except the

.git and packages folders

In order to prevent downloading all these files again and make faster the build process.
I tried adding 2 exclude conditions but is not working (everything gets deleted).

packages/**

.git/**

Also adding 1 exclude condition comma separated (nothing gets deleted)

packages/**, .git/**

Also adding 1 exclude condition space separated (nothing gets deleted)

packages/** .git/**

Any ideas on why is failing?

Comment: Did you try prefixing your directories with **/  Also, try writing a simple script for the custom delete command that will write the files and folders to be deleted to a file that way you can verify if it is the cleanup plug-in that's deleting them or some other part of Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following;

```
**/.git/* and **/*.pack
```

Hope that helps :)